# How to display the value userName in home.component.html (Angular)

Tags: angular, router

How to display the value userName in home.component.html ?

home/home.component.html:

```
<p>
You are logged in!   {{ userName }}  
</p>
```

class HomeComponent home/home.component.ts:

```
import {AuthService} from './../auth/auth.service';
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {User} from '../auth/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _data: AuthService) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

login/login.component.html:

```
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    User * <input matInput formControlName="userName" required>
    <br />
    Password * <input matInput type="password" formControlName="password" required>                      
    <br />   
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Login</button>
</form> 
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

login/login.component.ts:

```
import {AuthService} from './../auth/auth.service';
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

form: FormGroup;
private formSubmitAttempt: boolean;

constructor(
  private fb: FormBuilder,
  private authService: AuthService
) {}

ngOnInit() {

   this.form = this.fb.group({
      userName: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
   });
}

   onSubmit() {
     if (this.form.valid) {
       this.authService.login(this.form.value);
     }
     this.formSubmitAttempt = true;
    }
}
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth.guard';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

    const routes: Routes = [
        { path: '',
          component: HomeComponent,
          canActivate: [AuthGuard]
        },
        { path: 'login',
          component: LoginComponent
        },
        { path: '**',
          redirectTo: ''
        }
    ];


@NgModule({
     imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
     exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
```

}

app.modules.ts:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {AppMaterialModule} from './app-material/app-material.module';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AuthService} from './auth/auth.service';
import {AuthGuard} from './auth/auth.guard';
import './rxjs-operators';

 @NgModule({
   declarations: [
     AppComponent,      
     HomeComponent, 
     LoginComponent     
   ],
  imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     AppRoutingModule,
     ReactiveFormsModule,
     BrowserAnimationsModule,
     AppMaterialModule,
     FormsModule  
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

auth/auth.guard.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  Router
} from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

 canActivate(
   next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
   state: RouterStateSnapshot
 ): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.authService.isLoggedIn       // {1}
   .take(1)                               // {2}
   .map((isLoggedIn: boolean) => {        // {3}
     if (!isLoggedIn) {
       this.router.navigate(['/login']);  // {4}
       return false;
      }
      return true;
   });
 }
}
```

auth/auth.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { User } from './user';

@Injectable()


export class AuthService {
  private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false); // {1}

  get isLoggedIn() {
  return this.loggedIn.asObservable(); // {2}
}

constructor(
  private router: Router
) {}

 login(user: User) {
   if (user.userName !== '' && user.password !== '' )  { // {3}
     this.loggedIn.next(true);
     this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
 }
 getUserName(user: User) {
   return user.userName;
 }
 logout() {                            // {4}
   this.loggedIn.next(false);
   this.router.navigate(['/login']);
 }

}
```

auth/user.ts:

```
export interface User {
  userName: string;
  password: string;
}
```

I am trying to get the getUserName method, but it does not work

Comment: Are you sure that is `{{userName}}` and not `{{User.userName}}`? If you want to use the method: then call it `get UserName() {...}` or simply use in homepage.component `userName = User.getUserName(user)`

Comment: What does `Does not work` mean ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should store value of user name if he is logged in:

```
export class AuthService {
  private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false); // {1}
  private loggedUser= new BehaviorSubject<User>(<User>{}); // {1}
  get isLoggedIn() {
  return this.loggedIn.asObservable(); // {2}
}

 login(user: User) {
   if (user.userName !== '' && user.password !== '' )  { // {3}
     this.loggedIn.next(true);
this.loggedUser.next(user);
     this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
 }

 getUserName() {
   return loggedUser.getValue().userName;
 }
```

And then in your home component:

```
userName:string;
  ngOnInit() {
this.userName = _data.getUserName();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the post, but displays the error in the npm console:

Error in src/app/auth/auth.service.ts (11,24): error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

line:

```
private loggedUser = new BehaviorSubject<User>();
```

class AuthService  in auth/auth.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { User } from './user';

@Injectable()


export class AuthService {
  private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  private loggedUser = new BehaviorSubject<User>();

  get isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
  }

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {}

    login(user: User) {
      if (user.userName !== '' && user.password !== '' )  {
        this.loggedIn.next(true);
        this.loggedUser.next(user);
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
    }
    getUserName() {
      return this.loggedUser.getValue().userName;
    }
    logout() {
      this.loggedIn.next(false);
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }

}
```

Comment: works, only this error from the console:
Error in src/app/auth/auth.service.ts (11,24): error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

Comment: private loggedUser = new BehaviorSubject<User>(new User());

Comment: private loggedUser = new BehaviorSubject<User>(new User);              
'User' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: new User() not new User

Comment: private loggedUser = new BehaviorSubject<User>(new User());  Same error message:  'User' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: oh User is an interface so just write   new BehaviorSubject<User>(<User>{});

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works BehaviorSubject<User>(<User>{});